# Infinite recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I`m searching for a example of infinite horizontal recyclerview. The idea is when the last item is visible automatically the existing items to be added to the end of the list if the used is scrolling to right or to left of the existing list if the used has scrolled to left, making the feeling that the recyclerview items are repeatable.